# Actionscript 3.0 Point Object not picked up by Garbage Collection

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, point

I have just been trying to fix a few memory leaks in my project and have discovered an interesting problem. It seems like a vast majority of my 'Point' objects are not being picked up by the Garbage Collector. Each frame it creates about 5000 new Point objects and less than 10% of them seem to ever get picked up. Even when you use code like this:

```
var tempPoint :Point = new Point();
tempPoint = null;
```

Even if I repeat it over 500 times, only a tiny fraction seem to be erased. This is really stating to get on my nerves now and I was wondering if anyone has encountered this before, knows how to solve it / get around it, or cares to enlighten me on what exactly I am doing wrong.

Would love to know anyone's thoughts on this

ps. I am using The Miner to check the resource usage

Edit: Have now done a quick check where I had the program running for about an hour and although the memory usage went up about 140MB it did start garbage collecting at this point and did not go past that. So they will be picked up but not until you have several million created ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will quote **[Grant Skinner](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html)** to answer your question:

> A *very* important thing to understand about the Garbage Collector in FP9 is that it’s operations are deferred. Your objects will not be removed immediately when all active references are deleted, instead they will be removed at some indeterminate time in the future (from a developer standpoint).
>
> [...]
>
> It’s very important to remember that you have no control over when your objects will be deallocated, so you must make them as inert as possible when you are finished with them.

So, what's happened with your code? FP created something near 5000 instances of `Point`. If you look the memory usage over time you may notice that it will drop to the initial value after a few seconds.

The best way to avoid this behaviour is to *pool* the created objects and reuse them instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Florent, I've just gotten back into work and will test this now, but as I said to Jonatan earlier, I think you may be correct in this and I'm just being a bit impatient. Unfortunately the Starling method DisplayObject.globalToLocal uses Matrix.transformPoint, which always creates a new object, so if I want to avoid this, I expect I will have to create my own matrix transformation function that does not create a new object. Since this is really the only memory leak in the code, I will come back to it later when I don't have other features to add. Cheers for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

How long are you waiting for them to be erased?

If you are creating 5000 new objects per frame, it's probably a good idea to use an object pool.

```
class PointPool {
    private var _points:Vector.<Point>;

    public function PointPool() {
        _points = new Vector.<Point>();
    }

    public function createPoint(x:Number, y:Number):Point {
        var p:Point = null;

        if( _points.length > 0 ) 
            p = _points.pop();
        else
            p = new Point();

        p.x = x;
        p.y = y;

        return p;
   }

   public function returnPoint(point:Point):void {
        _points.push(point);
   }
}
```

Just a thought :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jonatan, I think you may be onto something with that first thought, I'm probably being a bit impatient, I'll run a test over an extended period of time (I've only done about 3 minutes of waiting at the mo) and see if they get collected then. I just don't like seeing the memory usage rise! I think that the object pool situation is not the solution for me, I'm seeing this problem occur in the Starling DisplayObject.globalToLocal function, so the point is only required briefly and should be recalculate on the next relevant event, no need to store it past that. Cheers :)